# VSCode 1.26.1, Workspaces/Virtual folders + Angular App + TFS

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am working with an Angular 6 app using VS Code.

My angular app is located in e:\workingfolder\angular-app

I have a set of json files located at e:\common\files\json*.json

I would like the json files to be accessible by the angular CLI web server while I am debugging my application via "ng serve" so that I can do a HTTP Get  - e.g:

```
this.http.get('./common/files/json/foo.json', {responseType:'text'});
```

I've tried symlinks in DOS, but that's a no-go from the CLI, and is frankly kind of a kludge.

In Visual Studio, you can add a "virtual folder" that has a virtual place in the project folder, but which is physically located elsewhere.  Is there something similar that VSCode offers?  I've looked at Multiple Workspace Roots, but I'm perplexed how to make these files accessible to the CLI web server.

TIA

Comment: You might wanna check this out:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.virtual-folders

Comment: Do you want to consider alternatives to reading json files from your File System?

Comment: I did look into the use of require(..), but I do have a requirement that the file contents can actually be a mix of mime types (not just JSON). require only plays nicely with formatted .js or ,json.  If you have a suggestion for all "text/*" mime content I'm all ears!

Comment: Well. I just have a suggestion if your file contains only json. You might want to try accessing the files by relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

i would say just keep them hosted on seperate port with an `http-server` npm package i.e  go to your directory *e:\common\files\json*  in git bash or cmd and hit `http-server` command it will give you a url like

> http://192.168.0.106:8080/res.json

which you can hit a request to in debug mode.

Comment: this is a good suggestion - it'd be best if there was more of a turnkey integrated solution.  Will keep this in mind as an alternative, as it is very easy to implement and maintain.  Thanks.